# IntegerQ and Element Integers give different results in one case

Tags: expression-test

```
f1[x_] := IntegerQ[x]

f2[x_] := Element[x, Integers]
```

Both functions give identical results in everything except for such case:

```
f1[4.]

(*False*)

f2[4.]
(*4. \[Element] Integers*)
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Precisely this is documented in the Details for `IntegerQ`.  "`IntegerQ[` _expr_ `]` returns `False` unless _expr_ is manifestly an integer (i.e. has head `Integer`).  `Simplify[` _expr_ `\[Element]Integers]` can be used to try to determine whether an expression is mathematically equal to an integer."

Comment: It is unfortunate that data types do not always correspond to number classes even though they may share the same name. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19708/discussion-on-question-by-david-carraher-real-numbers-in-the-wolfram-language for a discussion about data types versus classes of numbers (Real numbers).

Comment: Another way to look at this, the `4.` is an approximate real number. If you interpret it as `4+O($MachineEpsilon)`, then you can see it may or may not be an exact integer so `Element` properly returns unevaluated .

Answer (score 4):

`IntegerQ` is meant for programming and tests for a data type, not whether something is mathematically an integer.

`Element` is meant to represent a mathematical concept.

The two are not interchangeable.

Functions ending in `...Q` always return `True` or `False`.  Since the data type of `x` is not `Integer` (in the programming sense---it's a symbol), `IntegerQ[x]` returns `False`.

Comment: I am not questioning about ...Q logical tests functions. I am questioning why Element does not recognize that 4. is a real number as it does with 4.1. If you try to used Element with any domain (Integers, Reals, Complexes) it works perfectly except for this specific case.

Comment: @Algohi Because all `4.0`, `4`, `4/1`, `8/2`, etc. are different representations of the same mathematical concept, the number `four`, which is a member of `Z`. `Element` tests mathematical set-inclusion while `IntegerQ` checks if the argument is "structurally" represented in *Mathematica* as an `Integer` type or not.

Comment: Also compare to 4. == 4 and 4. === 4